# Creating Signed URLs for Amazon CloudFront

Tags: python, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

Short version: How do I make signed URLs "on-demand" to mimic Nginx's X-Accel-Redirect behavior (i.e. protecting downloads) with Amazon CloudFront/S3 using Python.

I've got a Django server up and running with an Nginx front-end. I've been getting hammered with requests to it and recently had to install it as a [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org) WSGI application to prevent it from crashing in FastCGI mode.

Now I'm having an issue with my server getting bogged down (i.e. most of its bandwidth is being used up) due to too many requests for media being made to it, I've been looking into CDNs and I believe Amazon CloudFront/S3 would be the proper solution for me.

I've been using Nginx's X-Accel-Redirect header to protect the files from unauthorized downloading, but I don't have that ability with CloudFront/S3--however they do offer signed URLs. I'm no Python expert by far and definitely don't know how to create a Signed URL properly, so I was hoping someone would have a link for how to make these URLs "on-demand" or would be willing to explain how to here, it would be greatly appreciated.

Also, is this the proper solution, even? I'm not too familiar with CDNs, is there a CDN that would be better suited for this?

Comment: By the way, switch to uWSGI and your FastCGI won't crash any more.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[Amazon CloudFront Signed URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls-overview.html) work differently than Amazon S3 signed URLs.  CloudFront uses RSA signatures based on a separate CloudFront keypair which you have to set up in your Amazon Account Credentials page.  Here's some code to actually generate a time-limited URL in Python using the [M2Crypto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/M2Crypto) library:

**Create a keypair for CloudFront**

I think the only way to do this is through Amazon's web site.  Go into your AWS "Account" page and click on the "Security Credentials" link.  Click on the "Key Pairs" tab then click "Create a New Key Pair".  This will generate a new key pair for you and automatically download a private key file (pk-xxxxxxxxx.pem).  Keep the key file safe and private.  Also note down the "Key Pair ID" from amazon as we will need it in the next step.

**Generate some URLs in Python**

As of boto version 2.0 there does not seem to be any support for generating signed CloudFront URLs.  Python does not include RSA encryption routines in the standard library so we will have to use an additional library.  I've used M2Crypto in this example.

For a non-streaming distribution, you must use the full cloudfront URL as the resource, however for streaming we only use the object name of the video file.  See the code below for a full example of generating a URL which only lasts for 5 minutes.

This code is based loosely on the PHP example code provided by Amazon in the CloudFront documentation.

```
from M2Crypto import EVP
import base64
import time

def aws_url_base64_encode(msg):
    msg_base64 = base64.b64encode(msg)
    msg_base64 = msg_base64.replace('+', '-')
    msg_base64 = msg_base64.replace('=', '_')
    msg_base64 = msg_base64.replace('/', '~')
    return msg_base64

def sign_string(message, priv_key_string):
    key = EVP.load_key_string(priv_key_string)
    key.reset_context(md='sha1')
    key.sign_init()
    key.sign_update(message)
    signature = key.sign_final()
    return signature

def create_url(url, encoded_signature, key_pair_id, expires):
    signed_url = "%(url)s?Expires=%(expires)s&Signature=%(encoded_signature)s&Key-Pair-Id=%(key_pair_id)s" % {
            'url':url,
            'expires':expires,
            'encoded_signature':encoded_signature,
            'key_pair_id':key_pair_id,
            }
    return signed_url

def get_canned_policy_url(url, priv_key_string, key_pair_id, expires):
    #we manually construct this policy string to ensure formatting matches signature
    canned_policy = '{"Statement":[{"Resource":"%(url)s","Condition":{"DateLessThan":{"AWS:EpochTime":%(expires)s}}}]}' % {'url':url, 'expires':expires}

    #sign the non-encoded policy
    signature = sign_string(canned_policy, priv_key_string)
    #now base64 encode the signature (URL safe as well)
    encoded_signature = aws_url_base64_encode(signature)

    #combine these into a full url
    signed_url = create_url(url, encoded_signature, key_pair_id, expires);

    return signed_url

def encode_query_param(resource):
    enc = resource
    enc = enc.replace('?', '%3F')
    enc = enc.replace('=', '%3D')
    enc = enc.replace('&', '%26')
    return enc


#Set parameters for URL
key_pair_id = "APKAIAZVIO4BQ" #from the AWS accounts CloudFront tab
priv_key_file = "cloudfront-pk.pem" #your private keypair file
# Use the FULL URL for non-streaming:
resource = "http://34254534.cloudfront.net/video.mp4"
#resource = 'video.mp4' #your resource (just object name for streaming videos)
expires = int(time.time()) + 300 #5 min

#Create the signed URL
priv_key_string = open(priv_key_file).read()
signed_url = get_canned_policy_url(resource, priv_key_string, key_pair_id, expires)

print(signed_url)

#Flash player doesn't like query params so encode them if you're using a streaming distribution
#enc_url = encode_query_param(signed_url)
#print(enc_url)
```

Make sure that you set up your distribution with a TrustedSigners parameter set to the account holding your keypair (or "Self" if it's your own account)

See [Getting started with secure AWS CloudFront streaming with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549787/getting-started-with-secure-aws-cloudfront-streaming-with-python/6590986#6590986) for a fully worked example on setting this up for streaming with Python

Comment: inside `get_canned_policy_url` you set the encoded policy to a `encoded_policy` variable, but never use it. Is that supposed to be there?

Comment: Hi MattoTodd, you're right, that doesn't need to be there.  Also, boto v2.1 now supports this natively.  See http://www.secretmike.com/2011/10/aws-cloudfront-secure-streaming.html for how it works with the new boto code.  Once the boto version has been out for a while I'll update these answers.

Comment: Is there an example using create_signed_url method and [Boto 2.5.2 ?](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/cloudfront.html)

Comment: @ipegasus - I've added an example for `create_signed_url()` in a [separate answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16145598/45773), it is really quite simple now due to @secretmike's effort to incorporate his solution into boto, thanks much for this!

Answer (score 30):

This feature is now [already supported in Botocore](https://github.com/boto/botocore/pull/735/files), which is the underlying library of [Boto3, the latest official AWS SDK for Python](https://github.com/boto/boto3). (The following sample requires the installation of the rsa package, but you can use other RSA package too, just define your own "normalized RSA signer".)

The usage looks like this:

```
    from botocore.signers import CloudFrontSigner
    # First you create a cloudfront signer based on a normalized RSA signer::
    import rsa
    def rsa_signer(message):
        private_key = open('private_key.pem', 'r').read()
        return rsa.sign(
            message,
            rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(private_key.encode('utf8')),
            'SHA-1')  # CloudFront requires SHA-1 hash
    cf_signer = CloudFrontSigner(key_id, rsa_signer)

    # To sign with a canned policy::
    signed_url = cf_signer.generate_presigned_url(
        url, date_less_than=datetime(2015, 12, 1))

    # To sign with a custom policy::
    signed_url = cf_signer.generate_presigned_url(url, policy=my_policy)
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of that PR.

Comment: I used this API to convert a CF served URL into a CF signed URL which gives me like https://<mycf.cloudfront.net/<my_s3_bucket_obj>?Expires=1483228800&Signature=<signature>&&Key-Pair-Id=my_key_id. However, the URL never expires. Actual base URL https://<mycf.cloudfront.net/<my_s3_bucket_obj> already works as is. In fact I tried old date like datetime(2015, 12, 1). Yet the url never expires.  Is there anything I am missing to configure at the CF?

Comment: @SoundaR That is a different question, and the more appropriate place for that question is in AWS Boto3 github issues, and/or Amazon support forum.

Answer (score 16):

As many have commented already, the [initially accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2628984/45773) doesn't apply to [Amazon CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) in fact, insofar [Serving Private Content through CloudFront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html) requires the use of  dedicated [CloudFront Signed URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls-overview.html) - accordingly [secretmike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6624431/45773) has been correct, but it is meanwhile outdated after he himself took the time and [Added support for generating signed URLs for CloudFront](https://github.com/boto/boto/pull/357) (thanks much for this!).

[boto](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) now supports a dedicated [create_signed_url](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/cloudfront.html#boto.cloudfront.distribution.Distribution.create_signed_url) method and the former binary dependency M2Crypto has recently been replaced with a [pure-Python RSA implementation](http://stuvel.eu/rsa) as well, see [Don't use M2Crypto for cloudfront URL signing](https://github.com/boto/boto/pull/1214).

As increasingly common, one can find one or more good usage examples within the related unit tests (see [test_signed_urls.py](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/tests/unit/cloudfront/test_signed_urls.py)), for example [test_canned_policy(self)](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/417de058ed3636a8088168c28d2672972ace284f/tests/unit/cloudfront/test_signed_urls.py#L343) - see [setUp(self)](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/417de058ed3636a8088168c28d2672972ace284f/tests/unit/cloudfront/test_signed_urls.py#L16) for the referenced variables `self.pk_id`and `self.pk_str` (obviously you'll need your own keys):

```
def test_canned_policy(self):
    """
    Generate signed url from the Example Canned Policy in Amazon's
    documentation.
    """
    url = "http://d604721fxaaqy9.cloudfront.net/horizon.jpg?large=yes&license=yes"
    expire_time = 1258237200
    expected_url = "http://example.com/" # replaced for brevity
    signed_url = self.dist.create_signed_url(
        url, self.pk_id, expire_time, private_key_string=self.pk_str)
    # self.assertEqual(expected_url, signed_url)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use for create a policy so that I can give access to multiple files with the same "signature":

```
import json 
import rsa
import time                                                                                                                                                                           

from base64 import b64encode 

url = "http://your_domain/*"                                                                                                                                                                      
expires = int(time.time() + 3600)

pem = """-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----  
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"""

key_pair_id = 'ABX....'

policy = {}                                                                                                                                                                           
policy['Statement'] = [{}]                                                                                                                                                            
policy['Statement'][0]['Resource'] = url                                                                                                                                              
policy['Statement'][0]['Condition'] = {}                                                                                                                                              
policy['Statement'][0]['Condition']['DateLessThan'] = {}                                                                                                                              
policy['Statement'][0]['Condition']['DateLessThan']['AWS:EpochTime'] = expires                                                                                                        

policy = json.dumps(policy)

private_key = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(pem)                                                                                                                                          
signature = b64encode(rsa.sign(str(policy), private_key, 'SHA-1'))

print '?Policy=%s&Signature=%s&Key-Pair-Id=%s' % (b64encode(policy),                                                                                                                             
                                                  signature,                                                                                                                          
                                                  key_pair_id)
```

I can use it for all files under `http://your_domain/*` for example:

```
 http://your_domain/image2.png?Policy...
 http://your_domain/image2.png?Policy...
 http://your_domain/file1.json?Policy...
```

Answer (score 0):

secretmike's answer works, but it is better to use [`rsa`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rsa) instead of `M2Crypto`.

I used [`boto`](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html#installing-boto) which uses `rsa`.

```
import boto
from boto.cloudfront import CloudFrontConnection
from boto.cloudfront.distribution import Distribution

expire_time = int(time.time() +3000)
conn = CloudFrontConnection('ACCESS_KEY_ID', 'SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')

##enter the id or domain name to select a distribution
distribution = Distribution(connection=conn, config=None, domain_name='', id='', last_modified_time=None, status='')
signed_url = distribution.create_signed_url(url='YOUR_URL', keypair_id='YOUR_KEYPAIR_ID_example-APKAIAZVIO4BQ',expire_time=expire_time,private_key_file="YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_LOCATION")
```

Use the [`boto documentation`](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/cloudfront.html)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any policy exported in the signed_url. In any case I couldn't get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I find simple solutions do not need change `s3.generate_url` ways,

just select your Cloudfront config: `Yes, Update bucket policy`.

After that change from :

```
https://xxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/hello.png&Signature=sss&Expires=1585008320&AWSAccessKeyId=kkk
```

to

```
https://yyy.cloudfront.net/hello.png&Signature=sss&Expires=1585008320&AWSAccessKeyId=kkk
```

with `yyy.cloudfront.net` is your CloudFront domain

refer to: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/accessing-private-content-in-amazon-cloudfront/

[image]