# Generating unique URL based on user IP for Amazon cloudfront content

Tags: url, authentication, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have contents in Amazon cloudfront. These contents are private but will be given access to users when they purchase to get access to the contents for limited period of time.

I want the URLs given to the users be generated for that specific user IP or may be current session key. I am aware of the option of generating an authenticated URL to a private object that will expire in a certain time period. The problem with that is as long as the URL is not expired users can access the content from different machines which is not a requirement for users to have this capability.

Answer (score 0):

The expiring URLs you mentioned are made using CloudFront's signed URLs with a "canned" policy (see [Creating Signed URLs for Amazon CloudFront](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573919/creating-signed-urls-for-amazon-cloudfront/6624431#6624431) for examples)

If you also want to limit based on the requester's IP address, you need to use a custom policy which allows you to specify a date range and an IP address (or range).

See http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/index.html?RestrictingAccessPrivateContent.html#CustomPolicy for specifics.

Enjoy!