# Access Denied (403) from AWS Cloudfront Signed Cookie on Rails backed app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I tried whole day for this, but I couldn't...

A. I made a model for creating signed cookie. I got help from : [spacevatican.org](http://www.spacevatican.org/2015/5/1/using-cloudfront-signed-cookies/)

```
def cookie_data(resource, expiry)
  raw_policy = policy(resource, expiry)
  {
    'CloudFront-Expires' => expiry.utc.to_i,
    'CloudFront-Signature' => sign(raw_policy),
    'CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id' => ENV['CLOUDFRONT_KEY_PAIR_ID']
  }
end

private

def policy(url, expiry)
  {
     "Statement"=> [
        {
           "Resource" => url,
           "Condition"=>{
              "DateLessThan" =>{"AWS:EpochTime"=> expiry.utc.to_i}
           }
        }
     ]
  }.to_json.gsub(/\s+/,'')
end

def safe_base64(data)
  Base64.strict_encode64(data).tr('+=/', '-_~')
end

def sign(data)
  digest = OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new
  key    = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new ENV['CLOUDFRONT_PRIVATE_KEY']
  result = key.sign digest, data
  safe_base64(result)
end
```

B. Call cookie_data with 'resource' and 'expiry'. I got help from [randalv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29636496/3892320) for proper resource.

```
base_domain = '.myapp.com' # sample name
cookie_domain: '.myapp.com'

cookie_data("http://#{URI.parse(base_domain).host}/*", 1.hour.from_now).each do |name, value|
  cookies[name] = { value: value, domain: cookie_domain }
end
```

C. From A & B, Three validation of Cloudfront are passed - 1. Three cookies existing validation, and 2. Expiry existing validation, 3. Decoding avalible validation. I know these three validation because of error message on invalid request. But after all, I am always faved with same message - Access Denied.

There are some suspects.

1. My CNAME of Cloudfront is `'img.myapp.com'` (sample), But My testing domain is `'http://dev.myapp.com/#/home'`, and this is my local developing server(I changed localhost name).
   So I tried with many combinations of (base_domain, cookie_domain) :  (img.myapp.com, .myapp.com), (.myapp.com, .myapp.com), (dev.myapp.com, .myapp.com).
   But All Denied.
2. My Cloudfront & S3 Settings are same with those on [randalv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29636496/3892320). But I mind two things. 'Restrict Bucket Access' is 'NO' on origin settings of cloudfront. And I do not create CORS configuration on S3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved myself.
I had three defects, and now it works well after correcting them.

**First**, I changed expires to policy.

```
'CloudFront-Expires' => expiry.utc.to_i,
```

to

```
'CloudFront-Policy' => safe_base64(raw_policy),
```

Actually, I had used policy(custom) instead of expires(canned). During my trying, I had changed. But I don't know why expires version doesn't work.

**Second**, My base_domain is 'img.myapp.com' and cookie_domain is '.myapp.com'.

**Third**, Do not input bucket name on your final url. Very trivial mistake, but important.

Comment: Changing `CloudFront-Expires` to `CloudFront-Policy` did the trick, thanks!