# boto3: generate wildcard CloudFront presigned URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, http-live-streaming, pre-signed-url

I'm serving some private HLS content with CloudFront, stored in a S3 bucket. All the HLS content is stored in a `/hls/` directory at the root of my bucket.

I'm using this code for generating a `/hls/*` (note the `*` wildcard) pre-signed URL to access (the otherwise inaccessible) content:

```py
import datetime

from botocore.signers import CloudFrontSigner
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes, serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding

from my_django_project.settings import (
    AWS_CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN_NAME,
    AWS_CLOUDFRONT_KEY_ID,
    AWS_CLOUDFRONT_KEY_PATH,
)


def rsa_signer(message):
    with open(AWS_CLOUDFRONT_KEY_PATH, "rb") as key_file:
        private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
            key_file.read(), password=None, backend=default_backend()
        )
    return private_key.sign(message, padding.PKCS1v15(), hashes.SHA1())


def get_signed_url():
    key_id = AWS_CLOUDFRONT_KEY_ID
    url = f"https://{AWS_CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN_NAME}/hls/*"
    expire_datetime = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
    cloudfront_signer = CloudFrontSigner(key_id, rsa_signer)
    signed_url = cloudfront_signer.generate_presigned_url(
        url,
        date_less_than=expire_datetime,
    )
    return signed_url
```

This code effectively generates a URL but CloudFront responds with a 403 Access Denied error when I try to access the `https://{AWS_CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN_NAME}/hls/index.m3u8` URL (which is one of the files stored in the `/hls/` directory).

I have checked that I am following every guideline for configuring CloudFront and S3 for serving private content with pre-signed URLs. I am starting to suspect that this wildcard thing is the problem.

I am not sure what I can do to solve the issue. Any idea?

Comment: apparently you can: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-creating-signed-url-custom-policy.html#private-content-custom-policy-statement

Answer (score 1):

Here's some example code I found elsewhere on Stack Overflow that does this all in Python (since the example code from CF doesn't show this level of detail):
[Creating Signed URLs for Amazon CloudFront](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573919/creating-signed-urls-for-amazon-cloudfront)
Although I ended up doing a hybrid; I used the key/signing handling from the rsa_signer function in the canned policy example from Amazon in place of the sign_string function in the example I linked.

HOWEVER, if you want to use wildcards, be sure to make it a custom policy by including the base64-encoded policy statement thing as Policy=$policy in your signed url between Expires and Signature, as specified in the link Marc posted. I didn't originally read the docs closely enough and was getting pretty frustrated until I went back and read more carefully and included this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be working in UTC timezone. Replace `datetime.datetime.now()` with `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` and it should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HLS, you cannot used presignedUrl, you must use a preSigned cookie:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-choosing-signed-urls-cookies.html

```
Use signed cookies in the following cases:

You want to provide access to multiple restricted files, for example, all of the files for a video in HLS format or all of the files in the subscribers' area of website.

You don't want to change your current URLs.
```

PreSignedUrl is only for accessing a specific file, so it does not work for HLS.
You will have to specify a custom policy that includes the url you defined:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-setting-signed-cookie-canned-policy.html